# zfs rollback/recovery of snapshot on different server

Tags: zfs, data-recovery, rollback

I have created a snapshot of

zroot/jails/jail1

as

jail1@2020-01-10T17:31:40

on server1 and sent this snapshot to

zroot/backups/jail1

on server2

The snapshot was properly created on the server2 machine as

```
root@server2# ZFS list -t snapshot
NAME                                                  USED  AVAIL REFER MOUNTPOINT
zroot/backups/jail1/jail1@2020-01-10T17:31:40            0      - 2.75G -
```

How can I rollback/recover this snapshot on the remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server2# zfs send zroot/backups/jail1/jail1@2020-01-10T17:31:40 | ssh root@server1 zfs receive zroot/backups/jail1/jail1
```